# CMake-CPack Package Installation Path Nightmare

Tags: path, installation, cmake, debian, cpack

I've been frustrated by the the CMake-CPack for almost one week.

The bad thing is the CMake-CPack online documentation does not document this part well.

After googling, I found this variables to use:

```
CPACK_PACKAGING_PREFIX          # NOT documented
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX            # Documented, but the behavior seems weird
CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX            # NOT documented
CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY # Documented, but this variable does NOT work as the online document described
CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX  # NOT documented
```

What I am trying to do is: package a Debian package using `fakeroot make package`, when the package is installed by `sudo dpkg -i MyProgramPackageName`, install it to `/usr/local`, with a subdirectory `MyProgramPackageName`.  That is, all files should be installed under `/usr/local/MyProgramPackageName-V.1.2.3`.

I've been trying (CMake 2.8.3 and CMake 2.8.5) to tune these variables.  I tried so many combinations, but failed.

The only way succeeded is:

```
Set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr/local/MyProgramPackageName-V.1.2.3)
```

But this variable is NOT even documented, and the behavior cannot be guaranteed.  If you are confused with my question, please advise me when to use `CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY`?  because the documentation description about this variable is really attractive, and it is really what I want, but I just could not make it working.

Please advise me.

Peter

Answer (score 17):

I didn't find any documentation to support this, but I did find some bug reports and email archives that seem to suggest that the following is what you should be doing:

```
set(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR true)
set(CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/MySuperAwesomePrefix-v.1.2.3)
```

If CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX is not set, it will default to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. Now relative paths from `install(... DESTINATION dest)` will end up as CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX/dest inside your package file. This worked when I tried to generate a deb file.

Comment: I will try your suggestion next Monday, and let you know the results.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The paths used by the CPACK are taken from the INSTALL directives in your CMakeLists.txt files. This allows the result package to mirror what a 'make install' would do. This keeps the CPACK configuration to a minimum.

So, from an example CMakeLists.txt file:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS ${APPLICATION} DESTINATION bin)
```

This will install to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. If you wanted to place it in a subdirectory you could do it here:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS ${APPLICATION} DESTINATION bin/myappdir)
```

Or entirely different directory:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS ${APPLICATION} DESTINATION /opt/foo/bar)
```

Comment: I'm confused.  I'm using CPACK to package it, so that it will install the app to where I want.  In the `INSTALL` directive, I'm always installing a folder or files to a relative path to the INSTALL_PREFIX/DIRECTORY.

Comment: You only want a relative path in the install destination - it will install relative to the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX automatically, no need to specify.  Specifying an absolute path is a convenient way to get all this installing stuff messed up.